# How do I load the first video on my social video app quickly?

Tags: flutter, video, video-streaming, loading, flutter-video-player

We've just launched a social video application on flutter framework similar to reels and tiktok and we're facing issues loading the first video when opening the app as the waiting time is approximately 6-10 seconds. I'd truly appreciate if somebody can recommend a tested solution in bringing the loading time down to almost 1 second like Tiktok or Reels. Thanks ahead.

We haven't tested any solutions as of yet.

Comment: TikTok, Instagram etc loads content in the background, when you're not using the app. So when you open it you always have something that has already been loaded, that can show instantly.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Show a link to an example video file. The problem might be how it  is encoded (a download link means we can check if that's a problem)

Comment: @cmbellman this is not right !